# R Install and load packages from a specific location

Tags: r, package

I am using windows 7, I can't seem to find the solution to this very simple issue on the internet.

I get an error saying that cannot Install package to a location I don't know about (I:/R/win-library/3.5).

How can I change that so the packages are installed to a location I choose and so that it loads from that location?

I read about changing the environment variables in control panel, but R Studio is not listed.

Many thanks!

Comment: You tried with `?.libPaths`?

Comment: Hi Paccioretti, I have not. Do I need to write .libpaths("new path location")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the directory were packages are installed (and searched) with `.libPaths()`.
If you want to add a new directory you can run

```
.libPaths("new/directory")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works beautifully. I hope I can now create a folder in the same directory the file is and use that as the folder for packages.